# DirectX 12 is not supported on your system on VM with Nvidia L4

Tags: nvidia, gpu

I have a virtual machine at google cloud with the Nvidia L4 GPU to run 3D applications. I installed the Nvidia drivers according to the documentation, but every time I run an application, it doesn't run and this message appears:
"DirectX 12 is not supported on your system. Try running without the -dx12 or -d3d12 command line argument."

Has anyone ever gone through something like this?